# How to communicate PHP and JAVA

Tags: java, php

I have few PHP files which is internally executing a shell script. I have controller files written in Java which communicates with central database. The flow of data is as follows:
1) Execute PHP file which internally executes a shell script. Now controller has to be running on the same server at localhost so that shell script code can communicate with controller class and update the database. I have currently installed WAMP Stack on my system, but it seems it doesn't support Java. How can I achieve the communication between PHP and JAVA files in this case? Please do let me know.

Comment: why not using a database table to exchange messages and, possibly, commands?

Comment: you  can use REST and SOAP also